# Duvida com mapeamento FluentNHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Estou tentando criar um esquema para definir permissões no meu sistema e essas permissões são dadas ao perfil do usuário, onde pode-se escolher o que cada perfil tem autorização de fazer em cada módulo. Para isso criei algumas tabelas e estou em duvidas de como fazer o mapeamento entre elas, principalmente na parte de permissões.

No Java eu faço os mapeamentos nas próprias entidades e no NHibernate sou novo então ainda não entendi bem o conceito de como fazer os mapeamentos. Minha dúvida é entre relacionar a entidade Perfil/Modulo e Permissao. No caso eu criei uma entidade apenas para Permissao onde faz o relacionamento de Perfil(HasOne) e Modulo(HasMany), isto esta correto ?

Obs: Quando for definir as permissões para o perfil, eu quero exibir todos os modulos em um DataGridView com as opções de marcar checkbox (inserir, alterar, pesquisar, imprimir) e assim definir as permissoes de cada modulo na tabela `permissoes`.

Qual a melhor maneira para fazer isso ?

**Entidades**

**Perfil**

```
public class Perfil {

        public virtual int id { set; get; }
        public virtual string descricao { set; get; }

        public Perfil() {
        }
    }
```

**Modulos**

```
public class Modulo {

        public virtual int id { set; get; }
        public virtual string nome { set; get; }
        public virtual string descricao { set; get; }

        public Modulo() {
        }

        public Modulo(string nome, string descricao) {
            this.nome = nome;
            this.descricao = descricao;
        }

    }
```

**Permissoes**

```
 public class Permissao {

    public virtual int id { set; get; }
    public virtual Perfil perfil { set; get; }
    public virtual IList<Modulo> modulos { set; get; }
    public virtual int inserir { set; get; }
    public virtual int alterar { set; get; }
    public virtual int pesquisar { set; get; }
    public virtual int imprimir { set; get; }

    public Permissao() {
        modulos = new List<Modulo>();
    }

}
```

**Mapeamentos**

**Perfil**

```
public class PerfilMap : ClassMap<Perfil>{

        public PerfilMap() {
            Table("perfis");
            Id(p => p.id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
            Map(p => p.descricao).Unique().Not.Nullable();

        }
    }
```

**Modulo**

```
public class ModuloMap : ClassMap<Modulo>{

        public ModuloMap() {
            Table("modulos");
            Id(m => m.id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
            Map(m => m.nome).Unique().Not.Nullable();
            Map(m => m.descricao).Not.Nullable();

        }
    }
```

**Permissao**

```
public class PermissaoMap : ClassMap<Permissao>{

        public PermissaoMap() {
            Table("permissoes");
            Id(p => p.id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
            Map(p => p.inserir).CustomType<int>();
            Map(p => p.alterar).CustomType<int>();
            Map(p => p.pesquisar).CustomType<int>();
            Map(p => p.imprimir).CustomType<int>();
            HasOne(p => p.perfil);
            HasMany(p => p.modulos).LazyLoad();
        }

    }
```

**model**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não entendi! Qual sua duvida?  Algo está dando erro? Sua duvida é sobre a modelagem? Explique melhor!

Comment: @Fernando Minha dúvida é se o meu mapeamento está certo conforme o meu modelo. Veja que a tabela `permissoes` eh composta nela eu recebo o id do `perfil` e os ids de `modulo` e tbm defino as permissoes por modulo. A forma como eu fiz o mapeamento está certa ?

Answer (score 1):

> Esta resposta não tem intenção de solucionar o problema, mas sim de apontar falhas e sugerir possíveis alternativas.

**Possíveis problemas/falhas**

Partindo de seus esclarecimentos nos comentários, seu modelo está errado em relação a sua base de dados, pois em seu modelo `Permissoes` você tem:

```
public virtual IList<Modulo> modulos { set; get; }
```

E na base de dados na tabela `Permissoes` você tem o campo de relação com `Modelos` como um inteiro(`INT`):

```
modelos_id : INT
```

Como você armazenaria uma lista de referências a tabela `Modulo` em uma coluna do tipo `INT`?

**Sugestão**

Se eu fosse modelar esse seu caso, eu tornaria a tabela `Permissoes` uma relação entre o `Perfil` e o `Modulo` especificando as permissões para esta relação:

```
Permissoes
--------------------------------------------
id : INT | perfil_id: INT | modulo_id : INT | insert: INT (0 = false, 1 = true) | update: INT (0 = false, 1 = true) | search: INT (0 = false, 1 = true) | print: INT (0 = false, 1 = true)
```

Ficando bem similar ao que já era anteriormente.

E no modelo trocaria para:

```
public class Permissao {

    public virtual int id { set; get; }
    public virtual Perfil perfil { set; get; }
    public virtual Modulo modulo { set; get; }
    public virtual bool inserir { set; get; }
    public virtual bool alterar { set; get; }
    public virtual bool pesquisar { set; get; }
    public virtual bool imprimir { set; get; }

    public Permissao() {
    }

}
```

E o mapeamento algo assim:

```
public class PermissaoMap : ClassMap<Permissao>{

    public PermissaoMap() {
        Table("permissoes");
        Id(p => p.id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(p => p.inserir);
        Map(p => p.alterar);
        Map(p => p.pesquisar);
        Map(p => p.imprimir);
        References(p => p.perfil);
        References(p => p.modulo);
    }

}
```

Também criaria um `unique index` entre as colunas `perfil_id` e `modulo_id`, fazendo com que não seja permitido adicionar mais do que uma permissão para o `Perfil` relacionado ao `Modulo`.

Para exemplificar como obter as permissões por `Perfil` poderíamos ter uma consulta similar a essa:

```
int idPerfil = 1;

// Em lambda expression
IList<Permissao> permissoesPerfilLambda = Session.QueryOver<Permissao>()
    .Where(t => t.perfil.id == idPerfil)
    .List();

// Em LINQ
IList<Permissao> permissoesPerfilLinq = (from permissao in Session.Query<Permissao>()
                                            where permissao.perfil.id == idPerfil
                                            select permissao).ToList();

// Em SQL nativo
SELECT * FROM permissoes p WHERE p.perfil_id == 1;
```

Comment: concordo com sua dica, eu estava fazendo exatamente assim. Mas mudei o modelo pq quero exibir os modulos juntamente com as permissoes para poder o usuario ir marcando as permissoes que desejar conforme o modulo em um DataGridView. Como nessa imagem: http://i.imgur.com/YMRY6Qi.png

Comment: @FernandoPaiva, você não pode simplesmente mudar o modelo, não tem logica o seu modelo com a base de dados. Para ser possível criar uma visualização como da imagem, você pode ter uma lista de Permissões na classe `Perfil` (não é necessário ter a lista de permissões na classe `Perfil`, pois você poderia fazer essa consulta separadamente na tela especifica onde os dados forem solicitados). Da maneira que esta já é possível fazer isso, conforme a consulta de exemplo que demonstrei no fim de minha resposta. Você obtém as permissões por perfil, exibi no DataGrid e aplica as alterações ao salvar.

Comment: entendo a sua proposta, eh realmente como eu havia modelado antes. Mas como disse não dá para eu fazer como gostaria no exemplo da imagem que te mostrei. Mas muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @FernandoPaiva, da sim! Só que não de forma automática, na tela de perfil, você deveria ter 2 consultas, uma que busque os dados do Perfil e outra de que busque as permissões do perfil, e também ter 2 processos de salvamento, um para o Perfil e outro para as permissões. Não sei se compreendeu essa possibilidade?

Comment: sim, eu compreendi. Porém eu quero fazer para que seja de forma automatica no `DataGridView.DataSource` eu possa retornar todos os modulos(telas) junto com as permissoes possiveis e vincular tudo com o perfil selecionado em um ComboBox de perfis e depois salvar tudo. Estou tentando chegar a uma lógica de modelagem aqui para que consiga o resultado.